# How to iterate an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array like `var arr = { 30,80,20,100 };`

And now i want to iterate the above array and add the iterated individual values to one function return statement for example

```
function iterate()
{
    return "Hours" + arr[i];
}
```

I had tried in the following approach

```
function m()
{
    for(var i in arr)
    {
        s = arr[i];
    }
    document.write(s);
}
```

The above code will gives only one value i.e. last value in an array. But i want to iterate all values like

```
30---for first Iteration
80---for second Iteraton

Any help will be appreciated
```

Comment: In each iteration you are overriding `s` with `arr[i]`. Since `s` can only be **one** value, what did you expect `s` to be after the loop?

Comment: You should also be aware of what `document.write` is doing after the DOM is loaded: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over using the length property rather than a `for ... in` statement and write the array value from inside the loop.

```
for (var ii = 0, len = arr.length; ii < len; ii++) {
  document.write(arr[ii]);
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why `ii` and not just `i`?

Comment: @Jivings: Why not?  You can name a variable anything.

Comment: @Jivings It's an old habit that I picked up from one of my teachers.  I think the logic was that `ii` is easier to find and replace than just `i`.  I don't think I've ever had to use it, but it has become habit at this point.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your write statement is outside the loop. Don't you want it like this?

```
function m(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        s = arr[i];
        document.write(s);
    }

}​
```

Also, don't use in because it will give you ALL the properties of array. Use `array.length`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is i want to access the array out side of the loop .

Comment: @Nithin: Then you should have asked your question properly and precisely. But I think you gain more from reading the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), especially [about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object). You have to at least learn the basics of a language before you can use it.